# Unity3D VideoPlayer Clip Crashes on Android but Not W10 Desktop

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When launching the game, after the unity splash screen, my first scene is a small 15-seconds `.mp4` cinematic.

I have scripted said cinematic to load the next scene (Main Menu UI) after it has ended and it works flawlessly on desktop. When I build&run to test it on my Android device (Huawei P20), it crashes after the Unity splash screen.

I've tried using multiple `.mp4` as well as using converters to change their codec to no avail. I've also tried resizing and/or changing the resolution, but that wouldn't fix it either.

My only limited solution is using `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie`, but this is not something I want since I don't want players to be able to pause/skip the cinematic.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class IntroToMainMenuUI : MonoBehaviour
{
   public VideoPlayer VideoPlayer;

   void Start()
   {
      VideoPlayer.loopPointReached += LoadScene;
   }
   voice LoadScene(VideoPlayer vp)
   {
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Main Menu UI");
   }
}
```

Needless to say, the Android device always crashes, while the W10 desktop runs it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future in a similar predicament, I resolved it. The fault was that I had the video clip attached to the main camera directly. Apparently desktop will play it fine as is, but on Android it will always crash. I, instead, went to the Video Player component and in "Render Mode" I chose "Render Texture". I then created a raw image and attached the Video Clip in the "Texture" section. Like-wise, I then attached the raw image into the Video Player's "Target Image" section. It played fine afterwards.